# System "mail" command in R

Tags: r, system

I am having an issue with running the mail command through R's system function.

```
system("mail -s Subject_Line address@workplace.com < ~/email_body.txt")
```

Oddly, when I enter

```
mail -s Subject_Line address@workplace.com < ~/email_body.txt
```

in the Terminal tab of RStudio as well as in PuTTY for the server hosting the RStudio port I'm working in, it works perfectly fine (Subject is displayed, body displays, etc.), but when I run this off an R Script or the Console, it sends a totally blank email to my listed email address (no subject, no body, the "to" column is even blank) .

Any ideas what could be happening here? Sys.which("mail") returns /usr/bin/mail

Comment: Does replacing `system` with `shell` solve it?

Comment: @Miff it does not. I'm accessing a port of a linux server.